# I can't seem to get my dropdown code to function properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a drop down menu that when the drop down button is clicked it shows the sub menu. When I click anywhere else though it should hide the sub menu.

Here is my code:

```
function initMainNavigation( container ) {

    container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click(function(e){
        var dropdown = $( this );
        e.preventDefault();
        dropdown.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
     });

    $("body").click(function(){
        var dropdown = container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' );
        dropdown.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).removeClass('toggled-on');
    });

}
initMainNavigation( $( '.main-navigation' ) );
```

But when I click the dropdown toggle the sub menu won't show. When I debugged it in firebug, the `$("body").click()` event is triggered as well. I am guessing it's because the `'.main-navigation'` is inside the `"body"`.

I know that it works if I remove `$("body").click()`. However I can't click else where to hide the sub menu.

Comment: your code is working perfectly, but you don'r know how bubbling works

Comment: apply with `focus` & `blur()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your body click event bubbles to the .dropdown-toggle container so when you click .dropdown-toggle you trigger both events

```
function initMainNavigation( container ) {

    container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click(function(e){
        var dropdown = $( this );
        e.preventDefault();
        dropdown.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
     });

    $("body").click(function(e){
        var dropdown = container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' );
        if(!$(e.target).closest('.dropdown-toggle').length) {//trigger the  toggle only if the element is not .dropdown-toggle or a child of it
        dropdown.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).removeClass('toggled-on');
         }
    });

}
initMainNavigation( $( '.main-navigation' ) );
```

Comment: Yes works perfect now. Thanks! I guess I gotta go learn bubbling now...